# Is it possible to write (via sass commands or compiler directives) code such that SASS will output the final values of all variables to a JSON file?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

How can I compile a SASS file and have it output all the final values of every variable in a json file
I asked a similar question before and someone on here thought I was trying to get you guys to do my job. I'm just trying to see if it's possible at all before I go down a path that ultimately is a waste of time. If it is possible, I don't know the magic sauce to get started.

I have CMS themes that are built on bootstrap-sass, and other sass frameworks, and I'd like my CMS to be able to access variables that we use in the SASS files as well. Seems to me that if when I compiled the SAAS file, I got a CSS, MAP, and JSON file, I'd be all set.

I could write this as some kind of mixin, but even then, I'd need to be able to get

1. A list of all variables
2. a command to output json to the dist folder.

Any pointers on these items are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** you're using Gulp to compile your SASS there is a plugin that accomplishes this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-json

**After installing it, and given the following** `Gulpfile.js:`

```
var sassJson = require('gulp-sass-json');

var paths = {
    'json_root' : './bundles/theme/scss/variables/*.scss', 
    'json_dest' : './json'
};

var sassOptions = {
    errLogToConsole: true,
    outputStyle: 'expanded'
};

gulp.task('sass-json', function () {
    return gulp
        .src(paths.json_root)
        .pipe(sassJson())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.json_dest));
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass-json']);
```

**Given the SCSS file** `variables/colors.scss`:

```
$red: #ed1414;
$blue: #0351e0;
$green: #259208;
```

**Outputs the following json at** `./json/colors.json`

```
{
    "red": "#ed1414",
    "blue": "#0351e0",
    "green": "#259208"
}
```

So in order to have it re-output it every time you compile, you can just create a task that encompasses this task as well as your normal style compile task.

Comment: Interesting. Not using gulp but am using Koala, going to see if there's away to put this into the stack and make it work.